# Apache config issue

Tags: redirect, virtualhost

So I'm experiencing the following issue :

If I add this line in  in my site.conf file it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /contact-us /contact
Redirect https://www.website1.com/ https://www.website2.com/
```

I've added it in the , is this wrong or should I add it in a different line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, add this in <virtualhost *:80>

```
Redirect permanent /contact-us /contact
Redirect permanent /motorists/products /products
Redirect permanent /about/directorate /about
```

Restart apache and test.